# How to completely disable a mui/material Checkbox?

Tags: reactjs, input, checkbox, material-ui, frontend

I have this code for a `Checkbox` from `@mui/material`:

```
              <Checkbox
                color="primary"
                checked={isItemSelected}
                inputProps={{
                  'aria-labelledby': labelId,
                }}
                disabled={true}
              />
```

The problem I have is that, when it is `disabled`, this is how I see it:

[image]

I just want it not to work and not even show that grey tick when it is clicked.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by _not even show that grey tick_? When the `disabled` prop is true you can't check and uncheck it anymore. If you know which ones are disabled you can set the `checked` prop to `false`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that was how the `Checkbox` worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To completely disable a `Checkbox` you have to set the following properties:

```
          <Checkbox
            color="primary"
            checked={false}
            disabled={true}
          />
```